# get datetime with AM or PM in java

Tags: java

I have date in string format(yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss). i would like to get the same date with AM/PM also alongwith datetime.

e.g:

Input string --> 2013-03-12 13:23:30,

ouput-->2013-03-12 01:23:30 AM/PM.

Do we have any util class to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the string format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a`

`a` is the marker for the `AM/PM` marker: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a");
String formattedTime = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

Or

```
public static String ConvertDate(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a",
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    return df.format(date);
}
```

Comment: i dont have 'a' in simpleDateFormat only the datetime i have.

Comment: @SatishKumar here 'a' is add 12hour time to AM/PM

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this:

```
  Date date = new Date();

 //formatting time to have AM/PM text using 'a' format
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);

 System.out.println("Time with AM/PM : " + sdf.format(date));
```